# How to toggle a Button based on multiple states?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I've got a screen with several filters where each of them uses some variant of a `MutableState` like `mutableStateOf` etc:

```kotlin
var firstName by mutableStateOf("")
var lastName by mutableStateOf("")

Button(
    enabled = // <-- when the filter is "dirty" aka either firstName or lastName changes
) {
   // ...
}
```

I'd like to disable the `Search` button after the first search and enable it when any of the search criteria changes. How would I do this?

I've tried `LaunchedEffect(firstName, lastName) {}`, but it fires only once when the application start and doesn't do anything later when either of the values changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `LaunchedEffect(firstName, lastName)` should work if the strings are declared like this:

```
var firstName by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
```

But if they are declared like this:

```
val lastName = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
```

Then your `LaunchedEffect` should refer to the states' values:

```
LaunchedEffect(firstName.value, lastName.value)
```

Comment: Got it! However, `LaunchedEffect` is apparently supposed to fire only once.

Comment: What do you mean once, it should run as often as you need it to. @t3chb0t